# MYSQL script does not run when I use variable instead of direct text

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe someone can help me with one problem. When I use a variable (@ZZ) in script then my query hangs and does not finish. If I use a direct text instead of variable, then query runs normally. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this variable?

```
SET @ZZ = 'asf:urhkgsdmbn.nbc,rtwyu:oneci_Xjhsdu_Hfduerksfgas20110322112751:462516432';
SET @XX = NULL;
USE some_schema;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `hl`, @XX:=`id` FROM `doc` WHERE `uid` = @ZZ LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: It's probably not related to this but `uid = NULL` won't work as expected. You need to do `uid IS NULL`.

Comment: That did not help. But thanks anyway for idea.

Comment: I see nothing intrinsically wrong in your code. Unless you're able to create a small test case that reproduces the problem and post it here for us to test, I guess it'll be hard to debug :(

Comment: Well, that is just one small part where script hangs. EXPLAIN for select statement shows that there are 8 millions rows so it will be hard for me to create a small test case. It is strange thing actually, because all the other scripts with these variables works fine and it takes 0.5 second for those to be executed. And this one takes from 160 to 200 seconds (when I use a variable), and 0.5 seconds when I use exact string right in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just a blind guess until you get something better... The WHERE clause is evaluated for each row and you have quite a lot of rows. If it contains a literal, the SQL optimizer may arrange things in such a way that the expression is evaluated only once and maybe it can do better use of indexes. However, if it contains a session variable it possibly needs to read the variable again and again for every row because it may have been changed.

:-?

Comment: Last update from me :) Just found out, that query performs in console much faster then in MySQL Workbench. In console everything goes fine and fast